# PHP Error: invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to use this function at the bottom of a plugin's main PHP file to determine if one of its action hooks is being used by the tag specified. However, I'm getting a "Warning" on the 2nd `foreach` in the code below. Why is this? Is there a better way to see if a Wordpress action hook is being used?

```
<?php
function dump_hook($tag, $hook)
{
    ksort($hook);

    echo "<pre>>>>>>\t$tag<br>";

    foreach ($hook as $priority => $functions) {

        echo $priority;

        foreach ($functions as $function) {
            if ($function['function'] != 'list_hook_details') {

                echo "\t";

                if (is_string($function['function']))
                    echo $function['function'];

                elseif (is_string($function['function'][0]))
                    echo $function['function'][0] . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

                elseif (is_object($function['function'][0]))
                    echo "(object) " . get_class($function['function'][0]) . ' -> ' . $function['function'][1];

                else
                    print_r($function);

                echo ' (' . $function['accepted_args'] . ') <br>';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}

$tag = array('anspress_loaded');
$hook = array('find_do_for_anspress');

dump_hook($tag, $hook);
```

Comment: `find_do_for_anspress` is a string, not an array.

Comment: Also without a `{` this `foreach( $functions as $function )` only executes the next line of code..

Comment: @chris85 I made the variable an array because without doing so I get 2 errors: `KSORT() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE ARRAY, STRING GIVEN IN ...` and also `INVALID ARGUMENT SUPPLIED FOR FOREACH() ...` (2nd foreach).

Comment: Yea, ` foreach( $hook as $priority => $functions ) {` takes an array as input and outputs each value as a string. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. So `$hook` is an array in your function but `$functions` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Some errors from your code:

1.) `$tag` is array, but in your function it's used as string:

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>>>>>>\t$tag<br>";
```

2.)`$hook` is array, so first foreach works ok:

```
<?php
// for first row
// $priority is int 0
// $functions is string find_do_for_anspress
foreach($hook as $priority => $functions ) {}
```

Next you try to do foreach with string `$functions`, but it's not iterrable, so php says to you aforementioned error.